# I want to run a basic unit test within maven using the command line

Tags: java, maven, junit

I was task with creating a unit test just to check to see if tomcat server returns the /helloWorld. I am new to Java and Junit. I setup my folder structure to mimic main folder. I have the test folder /src/test/java. My test class is demoapp-test
When I try to just simple junit test using this simple code

Do I need to create a package as well?

I then tried to mvn  -Dtest=Demoapp-Test test
 I would get an error that says class, interface or enum expected

Comment: Do you have a hyfen/dash in your classname (Demoapp-Test)? That's not a valid class name. Try replacing it with _ or just remove it. Also, keep an eye out for case sensitive, the class file, class name and the -Dtest= classname need to have the exact same case.

Comment: Please edit your question to post the full command and the full output. Also paste your test class. It looks like you merely have a compiler error, unrelated to everything else in your question.

Comment: Let me verify,  I believe I changed the class name. I will run again  with debug to get more information